# Time zone offset change history dataset by date and city parameter

Tags: python, api, rest

I am searching for Rest API that will allow me to get all Time zone offset changes of city between dates.
Is there any API like this (not free) ?

For example:
Get --> Headers:

| City | From date | To date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rome | 2001-01-01 00:00:01.000 | 2020-01-01 00:00:01.000 |

Response:

| Timestamp | Time zone offset |
| --- | --- |
| 2001-01-01 00:00:01.000 | `+1` |
| 2001-07-01 00:00:01.000 | `+2` |
| 2002-01-01 00:00:01.000 | `+1` |
| 2002-07-01 00:00:01.000 | `+2` |
| ... | `...` |
| ... | `...` |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:01.000 | `+1` |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Maps API.

One call for `Search` --> `Get Search Address`- returns Coordinates (latitude and longitude).
Another call for `Timezone` --> `Get Timezone By Coordinates` - returns times zones (historical, current, future).